# GitHub SAML SSO ( cloud enterprise)

Tags: go, github, github-api, saml, saml-2.0

I wanted to integrate GitHub saml sso for the project. I have a custom IDP and from the SP initiated saml flow, like getting to the `https://github.com/orgs/ORG-NAME/sso` and then sso getting successful, but then GitHub asks for the password with prefilled username in it. Is there any way to direct log in without asking for the password, as SAML is used for the passwordless sign-in only

```
session.CustomAttributes = append(session.CustomAttributes, customAttributes...)
administratorAttr := saml.Attribute{
    Name:         "administrator",
    FriendlyName: "administrator",
    Values: []saml.AttributeValue{{
        Type:  "xs:boolean",
        Value: "true",
    }},
}
```

tried to make it administrator, in case it wanted me to sign in just to get the roles etc but that also did not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but a useless repetition of the tag information, which should not even be in the title. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user scrolling through a list of search results will know what it's about. For help writing a good title, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these will help.

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-saml-single-sign-on-for-your-organization/about-identity-and-access-management-with-saml-single-sign-on#about-saml-sso

> Note: **SAML SSO does not replace the normal sign-in process for GitHub. Unless you use Enterprise Managed Users**, members will continue to sign into their personal accounts on GitHub.com, and each personal account will be linked to an external identity in your IdP.

https://halfday.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GH/pages/1723301889/Enterprise+Managed+Users+can+I+have+one+of+those

> Unlike the login experience on standard GitHub Enterprise Cloud explained above, **logging into EMU instance will bypass GitHub’s authentication and the request will go straight to your SAML provider.**